# Impresspages ipBlock default widget

Tags: ip, themes, impresspages

Can you set up a default widget to ipBlock(), same as you can create a slot and set defaults in

`ipSlot('name',array('id'='id','tag'=>'tag','default'=>'default whatever));`

?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot set up default widget to blocks. However, you can show your example content.

```
ipBlock('block-name')->exampleContent('<p>Any HTML you want.</p>');
```

Most common usage is to create a real widget, copy the source code that is rendered (HTML) and paste as example.

I hope this will help.

Comment: What about creating a page where you have widgets places through ipSlot with some default data and then render this page into this block using `exampleContentFrom($filename)` ?

Comment: you can create a feature request on GitHub. And we'll see what we can do about it.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this with the following code. 
It works fine with IP 4.5.2 and 4.6.0

```
<?php echo ipSlot('text', array(
    'id' => 'my_text_slot_1' . ipContent()->getCurrentPage()->getId(),
    'default' => '<img src="http://localhost/ImpressPages/Theme/MyTheme/images/my-image.png" alt="">')); ?>
```

okay, wrong answer but very nice to set non-static dummy-content into IP ;)